# Rex prefix decoding for intel x64 arch

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, opcode, machine-code

In the Intel documentation ["Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Vol 2A"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#three-volume), Table 2-4 shows the significance of the REX prefix's bits.

Can someone explain to me how to interpret when W=0? It says `0 = Operand size determined by CS.D` but I don't understand what `CS.D` means.

Comment: See Volume 3A, Segment Descriptors. In this case, it means the "default operation size" of the current code segment, which will be either 16, 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: @DCoder Why not make that the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CS.D` stands for the "default operation size" field of the *segment descriptor* associated with the current Code Segment. This controls the default size of addresses and operands, and can be set to default to 16 or 32 bit operand-size.

In 64-bit aka long mode (CS.L=1), the only valid setting for CS.D = 32-bit, **so a REX prefix with the W bit cleared leaves the default operand size at 32-bit.**  (An operand-size prefix can override the operand-size down to 16).

The default address size in long mode is 64-bit (an address-size prefix on an instruction overrides it to 32).

---

Segment descriptors are described in detail in *Volume 3A - System Programming Guide, Part 1*, chapter *3.4.5 **Segment Descriptors***.

The effects of the `D` field are also discussed in *Volume 1 - Basic Architecture*, chapter *3.6 **Operand-size and address-size attributes***.

Comment: Thanks. Thumbs up. Was not aware the the CS contain a default addresses and operands size. What would be the point of having CS.D set to 32 or 16 bit size?

Comment: @mathk: you can't, except for 16-bit protected mode.  (Not 16-bit real mode; 16-bit *protected* mode.  Yes that's a thing, no nobody uses it.)  But that's incompatible with REX prefixes existing: 0x40..4f only decodes as a REX prefix in 64-bit long mode, with CS.L and CS.D set.  It's invalid to have CS.L set but CS.D cleared; that combination is reserved.

Comment: @Peter, D must be 0 in long mode.

Comment: @prl: crap, I was thinking that D=1 meant 32-bit.  In my edit to the answer, I just said CS.D = 32-bit, which attempts to side-step the issue of how it's encoded.  Does it mean the same thing with / without CS.L set?  (I don't have the PDF open, and don't remember off the top of my head.)

Comment: L=0, D=0 is 16 bit; L=0, D=1 is 32 bit; L=1, D=0 is 64 bit; L=1, D=1 is reserved (128 bit?). @Peter